# Separate a string into groups of numbers starting with 0

Tags: php, regex

i have an array that has a bunch of groups of numbers in it. example:

```
44849, 0123401234
44786, 012012
44313, 012012012
44174, 012012
42631, 012012
41901, 012012
41654, 0123401234
38915, 012012
38456, 012012
38218, 012012
28883, 012012012
64892, 012012
63897, 01230123
63889, 012012
63583, 012012
63566, 012012
```

the first number before the comma is the array key, dont worry about it.

what i need to do is group each of these numbers into groups starting with 0.

for example:

the first row of numbers would become ['01234','01234']

second row would become ['012','012']

third becomes ['012','012','012']

and so on..

i feel like regular expressions might be the place to start, but i am not sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm, i figured it out. This was the solution:

`preg_match_all('/[0][1-9]+/', $in, $out);`

output;

```
62285, 012012, 012|012
48914, 0101, 01|01
47650, 012, 012
47269, 012345, 012345
46578, 012, 012
46538, 012, 012
45800, 012012, 012|012
45792, 012012012, 012|012|012
45705, 012012, 012|012
45676, 012012, 012|012
45587, 012012012, 012|012|012
45556, 012012012, 012|012|012
45471, 012012012, 012|012|012
45424, 012012012, 012|012|012
45413, 012012012, 012|012|012
45317, 012012, 012|012
```

just for some more info these are groups links for videos. each video will have a number of links for one server, then a number of links for another server. the way these links are stored is in an array with the 'scene number' being the 0,1,2 etc. i needed to see if when split up into groups starting with 0 that the chunks would be the same size and contain the same elements, to see if one server had more links than another. very specific i know.

Comment: your answer fails on this line `41901, 012012`, it will catch the first `01`

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern to match numbers starting with 0 after comma

```
(0[1-9]+)(?!.*,)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/279)

```
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  0             # "0"
  [1-9]         # Character in [1-9] Character Class
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
(?!             # Negative Look-Ahead
  .             # Any character except line break
  *             # (zero or more)(greedy)
  ,             # ","
)               # End of Negative Look-Ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

### [`\d+,|(0[1-9]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/sX0eX3/1)

This will catch everything you need, but in individual groups. You must iterate over each line and apply this regex to group them separately. Follow the link above for a detailed description of how it works.

I am not sure about php, but in Python the groups are separated by an empty string, thus it can be grouped in one single shot! You might be able to do the same in php - please let me know if you can. Remember, you can always iterate over each line to do this anyway. It is guaranteed to work.